# Implementation of semaphore in Queues in freeRtos

Tags: task, freertos

Is queues in freeRtos from the beginning also mutual exclusive, by that i mean, shall  i create some kind of mutual exclusion for writing or reading from a queue, or is it already implemented by the function xQueueRead and xQueueSend.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source in "queue.c" you will notice that xQueueGenericSend() and xQueueGenericReceive() functions are using tastENTER_CRITICAL()/taskEXIT_CRITICAL() macro pair to ensure atomic operation of the function, which, in a sense, is kind of mutual exclusion you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

FreeRTOS queues are thread-safe, you don't need to implement your own locking. See the FreeRTOS [documentation](http://www.freertos.org/Embedded-RTOS-Queues.html) about queues:

> Queues are the primary form of intertask communications. They can be
>   used to send messages between tasks, and between interrupts and tasks.
>   In most cases they are used as thread safe FIFO (First In First Out)
>   buffers